# nginx site slow to start up

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, google-cloud-run

I notice after adding nginx to my site, it's very slow to start rendering.  It takes a 3 second delay once it starts to load.

It might not be nginx, might be Google Cloud Run and maybe I just need to configure the server on that side but It's sorta weird that my site would take a minute to load.  It wasn't like this before when my site ran on Heroku, only after adding nginx and Cloud run.

So I have 3 containers running as Cloud Run servers:

- `nginx` (just this, nothing else.  proxy to index.html on client container)
- `client` (ReactJS app)
- `server` (DB, GraphQL stuff)

The cloud run servers running these containers are all configured with:

- 128Mi
- managed server
- concurrency: 10
- max instances: 10

Here's my **nginx.conf**, maybe I need to add more to this?  I'm running 3 containers so nginx is one, and then there are two others.  nginx proxies to my client (React) site and all 3 are hosted on Google Cloud Run as separate docker containers/servers

```
server {
    listen       $PORT;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
    proxy_pass https://ssss-client-lvpzkq4yla-uc.a.run.app;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass https://ssss-server-lvpzkq4yla-uc.a.run.app;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_min_length 10240;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/#server-slow-start